# Chebyshev and Markov inequalities

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality

Chebyshev inequality: Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space, $f$ a non-negative measurable function defined on $\mathcal{X}$. Then, $$\mu([f>c]) \le \frac{1}{c^p} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f^p d\mu$$

Proof: 
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}} f^p d\mu  \ge \int_{[f>c]} f^p d\mu \ge \int_{[f>c]} c^p d\mu =c^p \mu([f>c])$$

Of course we can have the Chebyshev inequality in a probabilistic setting. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be the stochastic basis, $X$ a non-negative  random variable. Then: $$ \mathbb{P}[X>t] \le \frac{1}{t^p} \mathbb{E}[X^p]$$
Markov inequality:

$$ \mathbb{P}[X>t] \le \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}[X]$$

So it would seem that the Markov inequality is a special case of Chebyshev ($p=1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: They are actually the same. The wikipedia entry of [Markov inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality) states that it is also referred to as Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: Note the measurable function $f$ and the random variable $X$ should be non-negative, or you can deal with $|f|$ and $|X|$

Comment: Yes, are the same.

Comment: As far as I know, Chebyshev's version was given in terms of variance of a random variable. His student, A. Markov, provided another proof and covered a more general case - see also this wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#History).

Answer (score 1):

alternatively，for nonnegative X and for $p$>0,

$P[X>t]=P[X^p>t^p]\le E[X^p]/t^p$